# Error using CGAL: class 'Alpha_shape_cell_base_3' has no member named 'hide_points'

Tags: cgal

I am trying to install the software [Sibaco](https://github.com/Sayan-m90/ProtienStructureClassify), but I get an error relative to CGAL class Alpha_shape_cell_base_3.

```
/usr/local/include/CGAL/Regular_triangulation_3.h:1230:12: error: ‘class CGAL::Alpha_shape_cell_base_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_cell_base_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_ds_cell_base_3<CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_3<CGAL::Alpha_shape_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Regular_triangulation_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Epick> >, CGAL::Alpha_shape_cell_base_3<CGAL::Epick> > > >, CGAL::Boolean_tag<false>, CGAL::Boolean_tag<false> >’ has no member named ‘hide_point’
```

A similar error is reported for the members ‘hidden_points_begin’ and ‘hidden_points_end’.
I am using CGAL-4.11.3, since for later releases of CGAL I get many more errors when I try to install the software.

Any help to address this problem would be really appreciated!

Comment: The issue seems to be related to the vertex type used for instantiating the triangulation/alpha-shape. Maybe look at [this example](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Alpha_shapes_3/Alpha_shapes_3_2ex_weighted_alpha_shapes_3_8cpp-example.html) and try to see if the types used matches.

Answer (score 0):

The cell base needs to match the triangulation. Since you're using a regular triangulation, the cell base must be a model of the concept [RegularTriangulationCellBase_3](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_3/classRegularTriangulationCellBase__3.html), so [CGAL::Regular_triangulation_cell_base_3](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_3/classCGAL_1_1Regular__triangulation__cell__base__3.html) for example.

As pointed in the comment above, the example [ex_weighted_alpha_shapes_3.cpp](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Alpha_shapes_3/Alpha_shapes_3_2ex_weighted_alpha_shapes_3_8cpp-example.html) shows a correct setting of vertex and cell for 3D weighted alpha shapes.

If you need to use some more recent CGAL features and CGAL 4.11 is too old, feel free to post the errors you get and we can maybe help you upgrade the code from that library.

Comment: Thanks. I still couldn't solve the problem, since the setting in my situation seems to me very similar to the example you pointed to. If I am correct, the relevant portion of code should be lines 80-114 of [this file](https://github.com/Sayan-m90/ProtienStructureClassify/blob/master/RandomHomology.cpp)